# Angular spec test cannot read property filter of undefined

Tags: angular

I am running some spec tests for my angular component that works as expected when I host it locally. However, a test is failing due to this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`.

All spec tests are failing as a result, for now I have removed the other failing tests and I am just trying the basic test first. My test class looks like this:

```
describe('RelComponent', () => {
    let component: RelComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<RelComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                AnimationsModule,
                ICModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                RandomMaterialModule],
            declarations: [RelComponent],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: BackendService,
                    useClass: BackendServiceMock
                },
                {
                    provide: ProfileService,
                    useClass: ProfileServiceMock
                },
                {
                    provide: UsedService,
                    useClass: UsedServiceMock,
                  },
                OtherService,
                HttpClient,
                HttpHandler
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RelComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    describe('Component Setup', () => {
        it('should create', () => {
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

The failed line of code in the actual component.ts file is this line, within a method:

```
        const records = this.dataSet.filter(d => d.attributes).map((d) => ({ name: d.attributes.m_name, m_id: d.attributes.m_id })).sort();
```

And `this.dataset` is created as follows:

In the class:

```
@Input() oData: NData[];
dataSet: NData[];
```

In the ngOnInit:

```
this.dataSet = this.oData;
```

There are references to oData in the spec test that seem to work as expected so I'm not sure why the dataSet is coming up as undefined.

EDIT: I have now put some console.log tracers in and I can see that this.oData is also being printed as undefined in the NgOnInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed this line in the `beforeEach()` section:

```
component.oData = relData.nodes;
```